# Create react app can't start: events.js: 288

Tags: environment-variables, create-react-app, npm-start

I created a new project with create-react-app: version 3.4.0 and then I ran 'npm start' and it gives me the following an error, I will copy paste it below this message.

I searched everywhere and couldn't find a good solution for this issue. A 'bad' solution would be to downgrade the react-scripts package to react-scripts@2.1.8 or another solution I think it will be to reinstall windows 10. Is there a better solution for this? (and still use react-scripts 3.4.0)

Error message: 
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\amoraras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.2
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0~prestart: cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0~start: cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\amoraras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\work\temp test\cleanreactstartapp\node_modules.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;H:\bin;C:\work\temp test\cleanreactstartapp\node_modules.bin;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm;C:\Program Files\nodej;C:\Users\amoraras\AppData\Roaming\npm";C:\Users\amoraras\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\amoraras\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\nodej;C:\Users\amoraasu\AppData\Roaming\npm";C:\Windows\system3;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem"
9 verbose lifecycle cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\work\temp test\cleanreactstartapp
10 silly lifecycle cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (C:\Users\amoraras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\amoraras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\work\temp test\cleanreactstartapp
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\amoraras\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the cleanreactstartapp@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Also want to add that I can't run any project that was started with create-react-app version 3+

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **windows** as I do here are the solving steps that worked in my case:

1. Go to View advanced system settings
2. Environment Variables
3. Add to path the following %SystemRoot%\system32
4. Reboot
5. remove node-modules
6. npm i react-scripts@latest
7. npm i
8. npm start

My problem was that I modified the system variables.